# Deserialize array of different types from mongodb to c#

Tags: c#, mongodb, .net-core, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a data with array in mongodb collection

```
"data": [
         [
           "FA3T1",
           16
         ]
       ]
```

Can anyone please suggest what would be the datatype to be mentioned in c# for the data to get deserialized.

I have tried the below options but it doesnt seem to work

```
List<object> data {get;set;}

or

ArrayList data {get;set;}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "does not seem to work"? Do you get an error or is `data` null?

Comment: It seems the data type is `List<List<object>>`.

Comment: Hi @Markus Thanks for responding
 
I get the following error 

Cannot deserialize a 'Int32' from BsonType 'Array'.",

Answer (score 1):

`List<List<object>>` should work:

```
        public class Entity
        {
            public List<List<object>> data { get; set; }
        }

        var document = BsonDocument.Parse($@"
        {{
            data : [ [ 'FA3T1', 16 ] ]
        }}");
        var result = BsonSerializer.Deserialize<Entity>(document);
```